# Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to pass a submit handler to my form. My `onSubmit()` doesn't `return` anything.

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = (data) => {
    const processedData: IEditUserRequest = {
        ...data
    };

    editUserRequset(processedData);
};

//Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <FormField
        control={control}
        name="firstName"
        label="firstName"
    />
</form>
```

ESLint throws:

`Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.`

Comment: Where does it say that? Is this ESLint?

Comment: Correct, ESLint

Comment: Tell more about `handleSubmit`

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat I guess it's an inner method of react-hook-form.